# iOS: Background / Foreground Events

Tags: ios, multitasking

I´m working on an application in which, when it is pushed in background via the home button, a timer should start and when the application gets back to foreground and the timer has passed a certain amount of time, something should be executed.

**My questions are**

1. How do I handle the events when my app goes to
   background/foreground?
2. Is there a special method or an other technique?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: every `NSThread` and `NSTimer` will be suspended when the application goes to the background or the device goes to the sleep mode but `VoIP`, `location` and `audio` services. you cannot handle any other event when the application is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation could look like:

```
#define YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL 60*60*5   //i.e. 5 hours

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //... your oder code goes here

    NSNumber *timeAppClosed = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults timeAppClosed forKey:@"time.app.closed"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

and

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSNumber *timeAppClosed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"time.app.closed"];
    if(timeAppClosed == nil)
    {
        //No time was saved before so it is the first time the user
        //opens the app
    }
    else if([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timeAppClosed doubleValue]]] > YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL)
    {
        //Place your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks i will give it a try and vote up if it will work! thx

Comment: should i then write my own delegate protocol to inform the class i want to update the data in it?

Comment: Yes you can do that, or you simply create a singelton or use a class method ... there is no specific need to work with a delegate in this case. Please accept the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

In the appDelegate of the app you have some delegate methods which you can implement.

You can check out the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol to which you AppDelegate should conform.

When the app is pushed in the background the function applicationDidEnterBackground: will be called. When entering the foreground applicationWillEnterForeground: is called.

Better not use a timer, but store a NSDate reference in the applicationDidEnterBackground: method. When your app is entering the foreground you can calculate the timeDifference using the stored NSDate using the

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

function.